# conditonal probability notation

Tags: probability

Can someone shed some light on the conditional probabilities of P(A∪B|C) and P(A∩B|C) and how they can be performed? I've search many places but I might be confusing the two. (Also, Pr(C)>0)

I know that P(A|B) is $$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)},$$

So, I assume that $$P(A∪B|C)=\frac{P(A \cap B')+P(A'\cap B)+ P(A \cap B)}{P(C)},$$

And $$P(A \cap B|C)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(C)},$$

Would my assumptions be correct?

Comment: it's the complement, (not a/ not b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $P(A | B)=\frac{P(A \bigcap B)}{P(B)}$, if you substitute $A \bigcup B$ whenever you see A and substitute C whenever you see B, you get $P(A \bigcup B | C)=\frac{P((A \bigcup B) \bigcap C)}{P(C)}$.

Similarly, if you substitute $A \bigcap B$ whenever you see A and substitute C whenever you see B, you get $P(A \bigcap B | C)=\frac{P((A \bigcap B) \bigcap C)}{P(C)}$.

Hope this answers the question.

Comment: is it possible to further simplify the equations? I just don't see how the or would break down

Comment: Have you considered using the Distributive Law, i.e. $P((A\bigcup B)\bigcap C)=P((A\bigcap C)\bigcup (B\bigcap C))$?